# What is the right way to add icons to tree-view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am specifying icons for a TreeItem like this:

```js
export class MyNode extends vscode.TreeItem {
    constructor(
        public readonly label: string,
        public collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
        public readonly iconPath = {
            light: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'light', 'name_16x.svg'),
            dark: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'dark', 'name_16x.svg')
        }
    ) {
        super(label, collapsibleState);
    }
}
```

and when I debug the extension or package it and install the vsix, icon does not appear and instead an empty space is shown. What I figure out is that the resources directory is not being copied to out directory (along with the transpiled code). What is the proper way to publish the icons?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is a misconception that all the resources (icons etc.) should be published to out directory. So the code in question is trying to reference icons from out/resources. But actually you can have your files (resources) outside the out directory, publish them and reference from your code.

The directories in the project looks like this:

```sh
node_modules
out
resources
README.md
etc...
```

You can add whatever you want in the published (vsix) items.

So once resources directory is there, you just have to go one level up in directories and reference icons directly from resources folder in the src.It works both in debugging and in published form. Update the code as given below should solve the issue:

```js
export class MyNode extends vscode.TreeItem {
    constructor(
        public readonly label: string,
        public collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
        public readonly iconPath = {
            light: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', '..', 'resources', 'light', 'name_16x.svg'),
            dark: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', '..', 'resources', 'dark', 'name_16x.svg')
        }
    ) {
        super(label, collapsibleState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default everything in the project is copied (provided it's in the project folder). However, you can exclude certain elements and `vcse` checks the `.gitignore` and `.vscodeignore` files to learn what not to include in the package. I'm not 100% sure, but I think `.gitignore` is only used if there is no `.vscodeignore`. Here's what I use in an extension's `.vscodeignore` to exclude all the Typescript sources, vscode specific stuff, test files and the typescript maps:

```
.vscode/**
.vscode-test/**
out/src/test/**
test/**
src/**
images/**
**/*.map
.gitignore
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. The point you have mentioned was not actually my issue but still it helped me in getting the things right. Actually it was my misconception that all the resources (icons etc.) should be published to out directory. So I was trying to reference icons from out/resources. But actually you can have your files outside the out directory and still reference them in your code after publishing.